# AutoCompleteTextView show all possible matches

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I Tried out the AutoCompleteTextView following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm) example. I use the following values *{Abbadon, Alchemist, Darkseer,..}*. If I test-run the app and start typing *"A"/"a"*, I don't get an autocomplete suggestion. Only if I type *"Ab"* or *"Al"* so there is only a single possible match. Is there a way **to show "all possible matches"**? So if I typ *"A"/"a"* it will show all entries starting with an *"A"*?

Comment: Try setting the threshold value to the AutoComplete
    `autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the reference of the link you provided set

```
actv. setThreshold(1)
```

after the line

```
actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

To know what does setThreshold(int) do,refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to try to make custom adapter for AutoCompleteTextview